# KineticJS - Dynamically Creating Shapes

Tags: dynamic, shapes, kineticjs

so I am trying to dynamically create shapes based on a number pulled from a database. I've tried the most logical way of wrapping a for loop around creating a shape and subsequently adding the shape into a layer. But for some reason unknown to me, it keeps re-modifying the same shape even though the shapes stored in the layer should be at different positions (and different attributes).

My code is the following:

```
function graph(w) {
        barLayer.removeChildren();
        var bar = new Array();

        for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
            var pos = i * Math.PI / 30;
            var scaleUp = (i / array.length) * 2.5;
            bar[i-1] = new Kinetic.Shape({
                drawFunc: function(context) {
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(radius2, radius2);
                    context.arc(radius2, radius2, scaleUp * radius2, (- Math.PI / 2) - w + pos, (- Math.PI / 2) - w + (Math.PI / 30) + pos, false);
                    context.closePath();
                    this.stroke(context);
                    this.fill(context);
                },
                fill: "#333",
                stroke: "#000",
                strokeWidth: 4,
                x: centerX,
                y: centerY,
                offset: [200,200],
            });
            console.log("Starting: ", (- Math.PI / 2) - w + pos, "/ Ending: ",  (- Math.PI / 2) - w + (Math.PI / 30) + pos);
        }

        for (var n = 0; n < bar.length; n++) {
            barLayer.add(bar[n]);

        }
        barLayer.draw();
    }
```

I've tried everything from putting the shapes in an Array to just creating a new shape and adding it in within the for loop. I'm definitely missing something.

I have done a bit of searching regarding this topic and I found one comment relevant to what I'm trying to do:

> Basically, you need need to keep an array of shape objects and push new objects onto the array when you add a new shape. Within the setDrawStage() method of the kin object, just loop through the array and draw each object. I’ll let you know when I get the lab published.

I've looked all over for a setDrawStage() method and I can't find much data associated with  it. He also stated to put the for loop inside the method which is a bit confusing as I do not only want to draw the shape but also store it in a layer (as I have done for every other shape).

Does anyone possibly have a solution? Much appreciated in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a JavaScript closure problem.  More on that:

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Try moving all of the logic inside the for loop into a function to induce scope.  Also, instead of using Kinetic.Shape, why not use Kinetic.Circle?

Comment: Thanks! It worked well now, never fully understood the nature of closures.

Anyhow, I am using Shape instead of Circle because I was drawing bar graphs (using radius as height) inside a circle, so shape seemed to be the most obvious route to accomplish that.

Comment: hey, it would be great if you could add a jsfiddle or the code directly. I don't get it to work :/

Answer (score 0):

X and Y in your script do not change as far as I can tell so your shape will always start from the same position?